# How do I make custom control based on scroll view with animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I have made numerous controls like pickers that had static elements. You could scroll it and pick the number like in standard picker.

But now I need to make a picker that changes its elements based on their position. Here is the image:

[image]

I want elements to shift color from white to another color slowly while they are being swiped, and change the size while they are moving. E.G. the central element will be filling with white and getting smaller size and next element should increase in size and fill with other color.
It should also be dynamic, if I go halfway and decide to swipe back, it should work as intended, returning the last central element to its position. So for each pixel I scroll the elements should change.

How do I attack this?
I know the basics, how to call delegate methods, I have this handled, only question is how do I animate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with scrollViewDidScroll delegate method, as it gets triggered even if the scroll view was moved 1 pixel.
I set up collection view with cells, and have it send scrollViewDidScroll to each of those cells. Based on the data those cells adjust themselves via CGAffineTransform (for size) and my own written functions that provide relevant color for each offset.